# JFET LNA with High speed amplifier

Tags: lna

In TI's LMH6518 [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6518.pdf), it shows a JFET LNA implementation:

[image]

What's the purpose of C5, R17 and R49?

Comment: Pat of pole-zero residue, needing cancellation in the DC-feedback loop?

Comment: It's dependent on what the load circuit is and your diagram doesn't indicate that.

Comment: The port 'LMH6518+IN' goes to LMH6518 positive input, and 'LMH6518-IN' goes to LMH6518 negative input.

Comment: Fig 61 gives you clues.